# Setting up an IPv6 router with two interfaces, why is only my config's LAN -> 'NET access not working?

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, ipv6, iproute

I'm setting up a linux firewall/router on Fedora.

I'm working on getting the IPv6 working.

My simple network looks like this

```
'NET
  |
  |
ATTMODEM
  |
  |
  | enp2s0
  |    2600:yyyy:yyyy:zzzz::53
  |    fe80::e310:84ed:bda1:a330
LINUXROUTER
  | enp3s0
  |    2600:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy::1
  |    fd81:17:15::128
  |    fe80::e310:84ed:bda1:a331
  |
  |
SWITCH
  |
  |
  | enp5s0
  |    2600:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:23e1
  |    fd81:17:15::7
  |    fe80::6d9:xxxx:xxxx:23e1
DESKTOP
```

Internal IPv6 is working.

Access to the 'NET from LINUXROUTER is working.

But I'm missing the last piece of it -- getting from the lan (DESKTOP) to the 'NET.

The details currently are

(1) LINUXROUTER

```
    ip -6 addr show
    ...
EXT 2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
        inet6 2600:yyyy:yyyy:zzzz::53/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
        valid_lft 2876sec preferred_lft 2876sec
        inet6 fe80::e310:84ed:bda1:a330/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
INT 3: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
        inet6 2600:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy::1/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
        valid_lft 2876sec preferred_lft 2876sec
        inet6 fd81:17:15::128/116 scope global
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::e310:84ed:bda1:a331/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

    ip -6 route show
        ::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
        2600:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy::/64 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp metric 1003 pref medium
        fd81:17:15::/116 dev enp3s0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
        fe80::/64 dev enp2s0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
        fe80::/64 dev enp3s0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
        default via fe80::4e12:65ff:fe9c:e3e0 dev enp2s0 metric 1024 pref medium

    sysctl -a | grep ipv6 | grep "\.forwarding"
        net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
        net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding = 1
        net.ipv6.conf.enp2s0.forwarding = 1
        net.ipv6.conf.enp3s0.forwarding = 1
        net.ipv6.conf.lo.forwarding = 1
```

(2) DESKTOP

```
    ip -6 addr show
    ...
EXT 4: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
        inet6 2600:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:23e1/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
        valid_lft 86391sec preferred_lft 14391sec
        inet6 fd81:17:15::7/116 scope global
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::6d9:xxxx:xxxx:23e1/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

    ip -6 route show
        ::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
        2600:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy::/64 dev enp5s0 proto ra metric 1024 expires 86397sec pref medium
        fd81:17:15::/116 dev enp5s0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
        fd81:17:15::/116 dev enp5s0 proto ra metric 1024 expires 86397sec pref medium
        fe80::/64 dev enp5s0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
        default proto static metric 1024 pref medium
        nexthop via fd81:17:15::128 dev enp5s0 weight 1 onlink
        nexthop via fe80::e310:84ed:bda1:a331 dev enp5s0 weight 1
```

ON DESKTOP, I

*CAN* ping6

```
    @DESKTOP
        2600:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:23e1
        fd81:17:15::7

    @LINUXROUTER, INT
        2600:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy::1
        fd81:17:15::128

    @LINUXROUTER, EXT
        2600:yyyy:yyyy:zzzz::53
```

can *NOT* ping6

```
    @DESKTOP
        fe80::6d9:xxxx:xxxx:23e1
        @LINUXROUTER, INT
        fe80::e310:84ed:bda1:a331

    @LINUXROUTER, EXT
        fe80::e310:84ed:bda1:a330

    @'NET google.com
        2607:f8b0:4008:803::200e
```

ON LINUXROUTER, I

*CAN* ping6

```
    @DESKTOP
        2600:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:23e1
        fd81:17:15::7

    @LINUXROUTER, INT
        2600:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy::1
        fd81:17:15::128

    @LINUXROUTER, EXT
        2600:yyyy:yyyy:zzzz::53
```

and, can *NOT* ping6

```
    @DESKTOP
        fe80::6d9:xxxx:xxxx:23e1

    @LINUXROUTER, INT
        fe80::e310:84ed:bda1:a331

    @LINUXROUTER, EXT
        fe80::e310:84ed:bda1:a330
```

BUT, I *CAN* ping6

```
    @'NET google.com
        2607:f8b0:4008:803::200e
```

I.e., ping6

```
LINUXROUTER  -> NET:google.com  OK
DESKTOP      -> NET:google.com  FAIL
```

What's the missing piece is to get that working?

Is it a route, rule, policy or other system config that I need?

Thanks,

Thad

***EDIT1/ADDITIONAL INFO:***

It's not JUST the 'NET I can't ping to from the LAN, it's also MODEM's GLOBAL UNICAST addresses, either EXT or INT

```
    NET
    |
    | 'ethEXT', Global Unicast IP [NET::MODEM::EXT]::1
    MODEM
    | 'ethINT', Global Unicast IP [NET::MODEM::INT]::1
    | DHCP6 server
    |
    |   enp2s0
    |   [NET::ROUTER::enp2s0]::53/128
    ROUTER
    |   enp3s0
    |   [NET::ROUTER::enp3s0]::1/64
    | radvd server
    |
    SWITCH
    |
    | enp5s0
    |   [NET::DESKTOP::enp5s0]::11/64
    DESKTOP
```

@ ROUTER

```
    OK   ping6 -c 1 [NET::MODEM::EXT]::1
    OK   ping6 -c 1 [NET::MODEM::INT]::1
    OK   ping6 -c 1 [NET::ROUTER::enp2s0]::53
    OK   ping6 -c 1 [NET::ROUTER::enp3s0]::1
    OK   ping6 -c 1 [NET::DESKTOP::enp5s0]::11
    OK   ping6 -c 1 google.com

        PING [NET::MODEM::EXT]::1([NET::MODEM::EXT]::1) 56 data bytes
        64 bytes from [NET::MODEM::EXT]::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=5.16 ms
        --- [NET::MODEM::EXT]::1 ping statistics ---
        1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms


        ping6 -c 1 [NET::MODEM::INT]::1
        PING [NET::MODEM::INT]::1([NET::MODEM::INT]::1) 56 data bytes
        64 bytes from [NET::MODEM::INT]::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.91 ms
        --- [NET::MODEM::INT]::1 ping statistics ---
        1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms


        PING [NET::ROUTER::enp2s0]::53([NET::ROUTER::enp2s0]::53) 56 data bytes
        64 bytes from [NET::ROUTER::enp2s0]::53: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.130 ms
        --- [NET::ROUTER::enp2s0]::53 ping statistics ---
        1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms


        PING [NET::ROUTER::enp3s0]::1([NET::ROUTER::enp3s0]::1) 56 data bytes
        64 bytes from [NET::ROUTER::enp3s0]::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.111 ms
        --- [NET::ROUTER::enp3s0]::1 ping statistics ---
        1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms


        PING [NET::DESKTOP::enp5s0]::11([NET::DESKTOP::enp5s0]::11) 56 data bytes
        64 bytes from [NET::DESKTOP::enp5s0]::11: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.176 ms
        --- [NET::DESKTOP::enp5s0]::11 ping statistics ---
        1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms


        PING google.com(mia07s49-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4008:803::200e)) 56 data bytes
        64 bytes from mia07s49-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4008:803::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=118 time=20.9 ms
        --- google.com ping statistics ---
        1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
```

@ DESKTOP

```
    FAIL ping6 -c 1 [NET::MODEM::EXT]::1
    FAIL ping6 -c 1 [NET::MODEM::INT]::1
    OK   ping6 -c 1 [NET::ROUTER::enp2s0]::53
    OK   ping6 -c 1 [NET::ROUTER::enp3s0]::1
    OK   ping6 -c 1 [NET::DESKTOP::enp5s0]::11
    FAIL ping6 -c 1 google.com


!!!     PING [NET::MODEM::EXT]::1([NET::MODEM::EXT]::1) 56 data bytes
!!!     --- [NET::MODEM::EXT]::1 ping statistics ---
!!!     1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms


!!!     PING [NET::MODEM::INT]::1([NET::MODEM::INT]::1) 56 data bytes
!!!     --- [NET::MODEM::INT]::1 ping statistics ---
!!!     1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms


        PING [NET::ROUTER::enp2s0]::53([NET::ROUTER::enp2s0]::53) 56 data bytes
        64 bytes from [NET::ROUTER::enp2s0]::53: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.533 ms
        --- [NET::ROUTER::enp2s0]::53 ping statistics ---
        1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms


        PING [NET::ROUTER::enp3s0]::1([NET::ROUTER::enp3s0]::1) 56 data bytes
        64 bytes from [NET::ROUTER::enp3s0]::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.500 ms
        --- [NET::ROUTER::enp3s0]::1 ping statistics ---
        1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms


        PING [NET::DESKTOP::enp5s0]::11(NET::DESKTOP::enp5s00]::11) 56 data bytes
        64 bytes from [NET::DESKTOP::enp5s0]::11: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.019 ms
        --- [NET::DESKTOP::enp5s0]::11 ping statistics ---
        1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms


!!!     PING google.com(mia07s49-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4008:803::200e)) 56 data bytes
!!!     --- google.com ping statistics ---
!!!     1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Comment: 1) default route on linuxrouter is to `fe80`  2) forwarding of 2600::/64 is to internal interface `enp3s0` 3) you want default route to  `enp5s0`

Comment: > 3) you want default route to enp5s0

Sorry, I'm not following.

I need to 'tell' LINUXROUTER about a specific interface on a specific machine on the lan, here DESKTOP?

Can you show an example of the 'ip route add ...' I need to exec on LINUXROUTER to do that?

Comment: something like `route add net default 2600:yyyy:yyyy:zzzz::53/128 0` (I no longer have ipv6 at home so I can't test further). I see that ipv6 on enp3s0 is broader ( /64 ) than enp5s0 ( /128 ) is this a copy/paste/edit typo ? are network part different (e.g. zzzz vs yyyy in your edited ipv6) ?

Comment: no copy/paste errors.  just cp'd from shell.  all this^^ setup is done automatically so far.    the IPv6 address/config is being pulled from the MODEM's DHCP6 server.

Comment: @Archemar A default route to a link-local address is perfectly normal, and common practice.

Comment: I tried adding default routes to every IP/interface combintation.   Either I'm doing something wrong or something else is missing.  I just can't get any connection to the outside over IPv6.  IPv4 is of course working perfectly.

Comment: You have a multipath default route that you didn't explain ( .. nexthop .. nexthop ). Also:  I can only assume that 2600:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64 == 2600:yyyy:yyyy:yyyy::/64 or more explanations are needed . Don't obfuscate what doesn't need to be. Beside this I can only assume your router's IPv6's firewall prevents routing despite the routing stack allowing it. Oh and OP didn't register account...